# Why these "exported" variables are double-defined?

Tags: c, binary, reverse-engineering, x86-64, elf

I am testing some 64-bit ELF binaries on x86/Linux.

I compiled `apache` server using gcc, with its default configuration (optimization level O2 I guess).

I stripped the `httpd` binary with `strip` command, and I use this command to check the `exported` variables inside the `httpd` ELF binary. For example, for the variable `ap_hack_ap_hook_get_open_`

```
readelf -s httpd | grep ap_hack_ap_hook_get_open_
```

To my surprise, I found two definitions of variable `ap_hack_ap_hook_get_open_`. As shown below:

```
1732: 000000000068ff88     8 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   24 ap_hack_ap_hook_get_open_
2263: 000000000068ff10     8 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   24 ap_hack_ap_hook_get_open_
```

Note that they have different memory addresses, which means they reside in different places in the `ELF` binary.

Could anyone give me some explanation about why there can exist two variables with same name, but different addresses?

Comment: They might have a different scope.

Comment: @WeatherVane, Hello, could you please explain more about "different scope"? They both have the attribute of "global".

Comment: It was just a guess, since you didn't provide any declarations or context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are truncated in the output. Use `-W`

```
[root@osboxes osboxes]# readelf -sW /usr/sbin/httpd | grep get_open
   540: 000000000027bfc8     8 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   24 ap_hack_ap_hook_get_open_htaccess
  1039: 000000000027c040     8 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   24 ap_hack_ap_hook_get_open_logs
  1072: 000000000003ffb0     8 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 ap_hook_get_open_logs
  1451: 00000000000404d0     8 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 ap_hook_get_open_htaccess
```

Comment: That's true!! I found it a second ago and went back to update my answer! Then I saw your answer :)